# How to animate javascript event listeners using css grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm struggling to animate a certain piece of HTML, ideally, I'd like the javascript to handle the animation with .fadein or something similar and not the css. PS complete noob to Javascript

I've tried animating it in the css, but its not taking

```js
let strips = document.querySelector('.strips');
let strip  = document.querySelectorAll('.strip');

strip.forEach(function(theStrip){
    theStrip.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        strip[0].classList.remove('hoverin').fadeIn(2000);
        theStrip.classList.add('hoverin').fadeOut(2000);
    });
    theStrip.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        theStrip.classList.remove('hoverin').fadeIn(2000);
        strip[0].classList.add('hoverin').fadeOut(2000);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="strips">
    <div class="strip hoverin">
        <div class="plus"><h1>title</h1></div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="strip">
        <div class="plus"><h2>title</h2></div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>content</p>       
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="strip">
        <div class="plus"><h3>Title</h3></div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="strip">
        <div class="plus"><h4>Title</h4></div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="strip">
        <div class="plus"><h5>title</h5></div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="strip">
        <div class="plus"><h6>Title</h6></div>
        <div class="content">
           <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ideally, I want the bar to close smoothly when the mouse leaves and open smoothly when the mouse enters

Comment: So you want only one `.strip` element to be visible at a time and the others faded out when it's hovered?

Comment: basically, that's it, at this stage the transition is instant and I'm pretty sure I'm going to cause some epileptic seizures by it and I don't want that